# Cómo obtener el Id del usuario logueado?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core

Necesito saber cómo obtener el Id del usuario logueado en un proyecto asp.net core, en asp.net mvc5 lo obtenía de la forma:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

pero aqui no me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crearte un método de extensión para `ClaimsPrincipal`:

```
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace myproject.Common
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// User ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string getUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;

            ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = user;
            return currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        }

    }
}
```

Y así podrías usarlo:

```
using myproject.Common;

...

var userId = User.getUserId();
```

Fuente: [ASP.NET Core: Get User ID](http://www.dxsdata.com/2017/03/asp-net-core-get-user-id/)